# jQuery: append removable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click a button which adds a div which contains another button that can be clicked to remove said div.

```
function addPanel(name) {
    var outer = $("<div id='" + name + "'>");
    var inner = $("<button>");
    inner.click(function() {  
        $("'#" + name + "'").remove();
    });

    outer.append(inner);

    $("#someotherdiv").append(outer);
}
```

When I call this function it puts the new div in place with the button. When I click the (new)button I get an error message that "#*name*" is not defined. Using a javascript / DOM debugger (chrome) I can see that the new div is present but not being evaluated as a selector properly.

I feel like this is something pretty basic but I can't seem to get my head around it.

EDIT - typo in script fixed - not from original

---

EDIT

```js
function addPanel(name) {
  var outer = $("<div id='" + name + "'>" + name + "</div>");
  var inner = $("<button>Delete</button>");
  inner.click(function() {
    $("#" + name).remove();
  })

  outer.append(inner);

  $("#someotherdiv").append(outer);
}

addPanel('div2');
   
$("#addButton").click(function() {
        addPanel('div1');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<div id="someotherdiv">
    Main div
</div>
<button id="addButton">add</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the single quote. Also you missed `)` at the end of click event of the button. Try like following.

```js
function addPanel(name) {
  var outer = $("<div id='" + name + "'>" + name + "</div>");
  var inner = $("<button>Delete</button>");
  inner.click(function() {
    $("#" + name).remove();
  })

  outer.append(inner);

  $("#someotherdiv").append(outer);
}

addPanel('div1');
addPanel('div2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someotherdiv">
    Main div
</div>
```

Comment: Have tried this with no extra quote marks - error message is the same 'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #newDivHere'  (paren mistake was my typo in SO - not in original code) ** also - attempts to evaluate the new div in the chrome debugger show that it's not available there either. Using a DOM explorer finds it though.

Comment: If you use my code properly then there should not be any problem. I've added full code snippet. @ethrbunny

Comment: Yeah - I'm sure there's something else going on with my code. This just seems to obvious. TY.

Comment: Note to future self - the problem was an invalid character ('/') in div name. Not obvious from error message.